# How can i verify if a resource has already an association with an other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'll explain:

I have this association:      Catalogue (1)------(N) Products

I want to add a product only one time and so the same product mustn't appear many times into the catalogue. Which is the method/action to control if the catalogue already contains a product?

These are the Models with their relationships:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :catalogue
end

class Catalogue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :catalogue
end
```

Comment: With a one-to-many association, each product can be associated with exactly one catalogue. Using 1-N, a product cannot appear in multiple catalogues, neither can it appear multiple times in the same catalogue.

Comment: Maybe you actually want a [many-to-many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association, with a [uniqueness](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) constraint on both, `catalogue_id` and `product_id`. That way, each product can appear in multiple catalogues, but only once per catalogue.

Comment: Could you show your `Catalogue` and `Product` models (just the part with the association) and the corresponding database schema?

Comment: Ok, but you think that many users can create a catalogue (only one) which can contains products that can also be added to a catalogue of an other user. It is like a user-cart-products.

Comment: Some example data would certainly help.